# Does the generator (base point) is preshared between the sender and receiver in elliptic curve cryptography?

Tags: elliptic-curves, finite-field, elliptic-curve-generation

Or the elliptic curve and the generator point are known to everyone?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

The curve and generator point are part of the domain parameters and therefore made explicit if you use a named curve.

Comment: Is the generator is known to everyone in the network or only between the sender and the receiver?

Comment: Everybody knows the named curves, and the name of the curve and the domain parameters are considered public. Only the secret (usually $s$) of the private key is required to be secret. The point of the public key, well, I guess you can figure that one out :) - it's not necessarily known to everyone, but it's not secret either.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, base point is public parameter in elliptic curve cryptography. Suppose that, your base point is G and your private key is k. In this case, your public key would be kxG. Calculating kxG (by multiplying k and G) is fast whereas extracting k from public kxG is slow. In other words, you can calculate kxG in seconds wheras extracting k from kxG last almost infinite with brute force attack. There are approaches to calculate kxG fast such as [double and add method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication) (aka binary method).

That's the power of the discipline.